# Client-server communication and encryption/decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, binaryfiles, ecb

I am implementing a website in C# and I have a client server communication that I need to carry out. Client would send 
(POST) encrypted data and server would read the data and response with encrypted response. The encryption that we are using is AES-128 ECB cipher.

The device is sending encrypted data in following format (this is a piece of data):

> 3721 b1cc 1759 3067 f993 7c3d bda9 4f04 547c ea1b 3974 2bd1 f213 74a5
>   2036 7927 e679 bab5 7bbc 3fbf 6a30 85e9 38a8 b877 594a d329 74bb 5d24
>   2088 738a 9978 cecc

**I am not able to receive it in the .aspx page in the page_load method.
 Can any one tell me what kind of data this is ?**

**Also, how do I convert a plain text to this kind of data ?**

I already have a decryption and encryption function.

When I use the above data in my decryption function after reading it from a file into a byte array, I am able to get the plan text. I have to use Encoding.UTF8.ToString() function to get the plain text from the byte array output by the decryption function to get the plain text.

But when I convert the response data to byte array and send it byte by byte to the Response.write(), I still get the original encrypted string, and not the raw binary data that I have shown above.

Following are the functions for encryption and decryption :

```
    public string decryptMessage(byte[] data)
    {         
        byte[] decryptedBytes = Decrypt(data, key);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
    }

    public byte[] encryptMessage(string plainText)
    {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText), key);             
        return encryptedBytes;
    }

    public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key)
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            csp.KeySize = 128;
            csp.BlockSize = 128;
            csp.Key = key;
            csp.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            csp.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            ICryptoTransform encrypter = csp.CreateEncryptor();
            return encrypter.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key)
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            csp.KeySize = 128;
            csp.BlockSize = 128;
            csp.Key = key;
            csp.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            csp.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            ICryptoTransform decrypter = csp.CreateDecryptor();
            return decrypter.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }
```

For example, the plan text would be **"Hello, how are you?"**  and the encrypted text would be **"Cxzx3miStNMIjP9zG1xlCme"**. I need to convert this encrypted text to the raw binary data like the one sample shown above and send it back with Response.Write().

I have tried using Response.BinaryWrite() but it doesn't send back the raw data that I need when i invoke test the page in the browser. It just gives me "Cxzx3miStNMIjP9zG1xlCme" or some other weird characters.

Comment: No, the ECB cipher does not need an IV. Sorry, I re-edited my post for clarity. when I use Response.BinaryWrite() and test the page in browser, I just get the encrypted plain text and some other weird characters. I need to convert the string to raw file data (I don't know what that is called, but I posted the sample of it in the beginning of the post).

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't know about ECB :) Do you have the encryption method that the device is using?

Comment: No, I just know that device is also using AES-128 ECB. What library or methods they are using to encrypt the data is not known to me. I was able to decrypt the device encrypted data using the code that I posted above, but that time I was reading that encrypted data from a file. It was not being sent over http post. So I know that my code can decrypt the data sent by device.

Comment: @Johndo you know what kind of data "3721 b1cc 1759 3067 f993 7c3d bda9 4f04 547c ea1b 3974 2bd1 f213 74a5 " is ? I have posted larger sample in the post.

Comment: If it's encrypted data, how could anyone tell what kind of data it is? It is the encrypted data, right?

Comment: well, when I encrypt the data, it looks like this: 3miStNMIjP9zGw9kw7RfMfHoYDBWp+dzuLBF6WdJBJx+y3KaEKIQtCMa. But I need to convert that to look like the sample data above, so device can process it and decrypt it. I talked to the person who programs the device and he said that is a unencoded raw file data. I do not know what that means or how to derive it from my encrypted string.

Comment: If you don't recognise hex, I'd suggest you're going to have bigger issues trying to work here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for response. I know it is a hex string but how does it get formatted to look like that ? Would you happen to know ?